# Element exists but Selenium says it doesn't

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to print text from a class with this code:

```
price = driver.find_element_by_class_name("text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render").text
print(price)
```

But selenium says that the class **text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render** doesn't exist and then gives me this error code:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render"}
```

Is there any fix to this or is it a problem with the site?

Comment: Sure. But wee need to see that web page for that

Comment: there could be 2 possible causes. 1> while your automation is running the order of the classes might be different. 2> this element is not visible on the screen, you may have to scroll down for the element to be visible on the screen

Comment: @Prophet the site is https://www.roblox.com/catalog/77359785.

Comment: @RahulJadhav if it is either of those how should I fix it?

Comment: for 1> place a breakpoint just before you try to find the element, see the element in Inspect element and observe the element. for 2> use moveToElement method and try to get the element text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element you are trying to access having several class names.  Some of them are dynamic, not fixed while this `text-robux-lg` is fixed and unique so you can use it along.
Like the following:

```
price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.text-robux-lg").text
print(price)
```

Comment: This worked although my other code for buying the product now throws an error:
`AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_class'`
The code for that is: 
`buy = driver.find_element_by_class("btn-fixed-width-lg btn-growth-lg PurchaseButton") buy.click()`
Am I going to have to fix all of these in the same manner?

Comment: There is no method `find_element_by_class`. It is `find_element_by_class_name`. And yes, it is preferably to use css_selector or xpath, not the class name in most cases.

Comment: Also possibly you do not need to use all the 3 classnames `btn-fixed-width-lg btn-growth-lg PurchaseButton`

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provide the snippet of the HTML element.

Anyway, if you target elements with multiple classes, you should use `xpath` or css selector. Here I assume it is a div element:

```
price = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='text-robux-lg wait-for-i18n-format-render']").text
```